# Beating Angband as a Warrior

Tags: angband

Is it really possible to beat Angband as a warrior class? If so, what strategy can I use, and which race/stats should I use when creating my character?

I'm currently playing a troll warrior; with stats split between strength and dexterity mostly, I'm getting two hits per attack. It seems like I will have trouble gathering all the resistances needed to survive at higher levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a dwarf warrior that I had gotten decently far into the game with. Warriors can passively identify an item's quality after a brief period of time. The item will be inscribed with a descriptor like {splendid} or {ego} when this happens.

Try to keep an eye out for a weapon of westernesse. It'll be the equivalent of having multiple  weapons with different ego brands rolled into one. Rings of slaying are also an okay substitute if an ego item or randart can't be found, as they can boost your to-dam on each hit. Bringing along some potions of berserk strength can work well in a pinch, too.

If you examine an enemy and discover that it can hit with acid, back off and engage it with some kind of ranged weapon. Just because you're playing a warrior class doesn't mean you need to stick with melee. In fact, that might be the one thing that kills you later on.

For that Half-Troll character where you had a 50% split between charisma and strength... charisma becomes pointless after a while, since you'll usually be swimming in gold and valuable items that could be sold for even more. The only thing that stat effects is your ability to barter with shopkeepers for lower prices. The points put there could be put to better use in either strength or constitution.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the eventual answer. I made a lot of progress so far (dungeon level 30 / character level 29), and forgot to update my question :)

Answer (score 2):

Warrior is the easiest to win with, just start the game as a high elf and roll until you get enough combined str and dex to start the game with 4 attacks(with a weapon of 3.0 weight or less). You will do the most damage being the only class that has 6 attacks, and have the most HP. You can fill in all the utility gaps with rods/pots/scrolls.

Comment: I tried this in Zangband, and it seems impossible to generate a player that has more than two blows per round.